# wrap text view around img view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

Good evening,

I am trying to wrap my text around an image view like the question is asking here:

[Textview wrap around View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626750/textview-wrap-around-view)

in landscape.

but I wish to not do it in HTML / CSS. plus, that question is 2 years old. I am hoping someone has figured out a work around with this.

Also, I wish to keep my portrait view the way it is with the img view under the text view i.e. no wrapping.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I just found this: http://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/ Which basically does what the accepted answer suggests but in ready-to-use widget form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around I can think off the top of my head and from previous issues with `TextView` formatting, the best way is to have, say, a `RelativeLayout`, and just place 3 separate Views inside of it. It will represent the `TextView` that is right next to the image, the `ImageView` itself next to the text, and then the last `TextView` under the first text, but with the `layout_width="match_parent"`. There is no other way to do this with the `TextView` or `ImageView` otherwise.

**EDIT:**

The only other workaround I believe you can do if you are so intent on using 1 TextView, I would suggest using `SpannableStringBuilder` with `SpannableString`. I didn't originally give you that as an option for a specific reason. If you go back to that link you posted on your question, one of the answers say they found an answer. I believe that person linked to a good resource, but they are wrong for what your needs are. When using `SpannableStringBuilder`, you are essentially creating a string that can have potentially many different version of a single string into one, like 3 different colors on a single string, or strings with 3 different sizes, all in one `TextView`. Like what you need.

Now the link talks about putting an image and having the text wrap around it nicely, but its not that simple, and that example isn't what you need. What you could do to provide it all in one `TextView` is to add line breaks after the first few lines where you know the image will be to the right, and then not do so after the image. But the thing is it still needs to go in a `RelativeLayout`. But instead of two TextViews you only need one. Just place the TextView at the top left of whatever the parent is and the ImageView to the top right of whatever the parent is. This simulates a `floating` element. But I think doing it that way is more trouble than its worth. It really is because you have to do calculations to figure out where to put the line breaks, etc. You are better off using two `TextView`s in which to make it look like you need. So in my opinion, DO NOT USE `SpannableStringBuilder`, but if you do not mind trying to figure out all that spacing, that does give you what you need with a single TextView.

Comment: I want my text to flow, not be divided up between 2 textview.

Comment: If you read my answer correctly, there is no way to accomplish this using `TextView` alone. It won't "flow" on its own unfortunately. There is also not an attribute that will make it do so. What you are asking is to make TextView text wrap around the ImageView like a floating image in HTML. Doesn't exist in Android XML. All you can do is hacky workarounds like mine or even something else you come up with.

Comment: Ok @Madonk I added some info for you that I didn't at first because I do not believe it is your best options. But hey, its your app. So if it helps, accept the answer :)