# How to fill the empty spaces with content below the Image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-layout

I have one ImageView and a TextView in my xml layout. I want to show the text below that i got by webservice on the right side of the ImageView. Can i show that text by using that one TextView ?

[image]

I tried to give    android:singleLine="false" in xml layout but no use.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

https://github.com/deano2390/flowtextview

[image: screenshot]

Example usage:

```
 <com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView
     android:id="@+id/tv"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:padding="10dip"
         android:src="@drawable/android" />

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="400dip"
         android:padding="10dip"
         android:src="@drawable/android2" />

</com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView>
```

your code:

for Text:

```
tv = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);                  
tv.setText("my string"); // using plain text    
tv.invalidate(); // call this to render the text
```

for HTML:

```
tv = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);              
Spanned spannable = Html.fromHtml("<html ... </html>");
tv.setText(spannable);  // using html
tv.invalidate(); // call this to render the text
```

Comment: i am getting text from webservice how can i set that text to html

Comment: You dont have to convert it to html.  dont use spanable just      tv.setText(yourtextfromwebservice);

Comment: how can i convert that webservice text to html @talhakosen

Comment: I edited my post check there , There are 2 types of usage flowtextview. one of them is html, other is  plain text.

Comment: lagy. even the sample of library is not scrolling smoothely

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed here :
[Textview wrap around View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626750/textview-wrap-around-view)
 and here [wrap text view around img view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875339/wrap-text-view-around-img-view)

Apparently, a solution is to use a Spannable and an ImageSpan as described is this answer [Textview wrap around View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626750/textview-wrap-around-view#5541588)

Another solution is to use a webview and make you layout in html.