# Is there an easy way to embed image and text in a `View` like shown in picture?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know it is possible using `WebView` and an html page but is it possible to have this GUI using xml layouts with only one `TextView` and one `ImageView`? Please note that text **automatically wraps** itself around image depending on image size.

PS: I know I can use two `TextView`s and split my text contents using some algorithm and set one part of my text content in upper `TextView` and another part in lower `TextView`.

[image]

Comment: look at this Question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526949/how-to-fill-the-empty-spaces-with-content-below-the-image-in-android

Comment: `FlowTextView` is the answer, vote for close please...