# How to use TextView to fill remaining space of a view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have following requirement in my android app.

[image]

How can i use to behave textview as shown in the above picture?

Comment: Interesting question, but anything you tried ?

Comment: u have to use 3 textviews.

Comment: I tried with RelativeLayout but it did not work. :(  Is this posible to do ?

Comment: Its bit complicated to achieve this kind of layout. I suggest you to create html page.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image) should help you

Comment: You can divide the TextView into two. I mean you need to use to different TextViews.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526949/how-to-fill-the-empty-spaces-with-content-below-the-image-in-android/13527178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since api 8 (Android 2.2) has a new interface **LeadingMarginSpan2**, which allows you to create text indent for the first N rows. In the image created by the indentation of 50 pixels for the first 3 rows.

Check out [How to wrap text around a picture of text in TextView](http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/textview/leadingmarginspan2).

Answer (score 2):

Please check out FlowTextView

https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/