# Creating a layout in xml with text wrapping around images

Tags: android, android-widget

I have tried doing the flow text with the images in xml and java and it works okay but not exactly perfect.  So my question is how can I create a layout that looks like a book with images and text wrap properly around the images.  Is there a way? and if so is there a tutorial or example which I can follow?

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
text text text text ¦ image ¦
text text text text ¦_______¦
text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text
```

I have read all the related answers to this question (asked previously by different users), but none of them actually explains what to do.

can anyone please help?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626750/textview-wrap-around-view