# How to let a TextView have multiple lines?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, textview

I want to show multiple line via TextView and strings.xml . I want to show first few lines until the middle of the page and other lines to show in full of the page. I want to show first few lines with same size of width page.

Left of the page is a picture and the right of the page is my sentences.

This is my code but this shows dishevel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/logoImage"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtIntroduce"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtIntroduce"
    android:textColor="@color/blue_text"
    android:background="@color/blue"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name="intro">.................  ....</string>
<resources>
```

How can i show this view?
Sorry for my poor english and thanks for your help.

Comment: AFIK, you will have to use multiple textvies for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to wrap text around a picture, like so:

```
--------------------
|..........| xxxxxxx
|..Picture.| xxxxxxx
|..........| xxxxxxx
------------ xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxTextxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I think the easiest option is to a WebView.  However, according to [this](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) you can also use image tags in a TextView.  I've never tried it myself, but I have used the other tags like so: `TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>some bold text</b> some normal text"))` so maybe something similar will work in your situation.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly,I want to show a view like that but when i use WebView, i should show a Web page of internet, is this true?? your link not work for me(404Error). Please more explain for me. Thanks

Comment: Original link is fixed.  I think studying these questions will help you better than I can explain:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626750/textview-wrap-around-view and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474012/android-ui-for-text-wrap-an-image/12971408#12971408  
Lots of options there.

Answer (score 25):

You could have a look at these three **xml properties** of the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

There you can define how many lines the TextView should have, and if there should be displayed dots ("...") when the text exceeds the TextView size.

Also, you can use **return** inside your strings .xml to start a new line: ("\n")

```
<string name="intro">This is the first line \n this is a new line.</string>
```

Comment: But when i use this code, my Text not good shows in different densities and sizes of mobile. Do i think true?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my first post on stackoverflow...

I think this is the best an simple way to have a multiline textView on android. Here we go:

1. Write your text in an external editor (ex. Microsoft Word, LibreOffice, etc) with paragraphs and multiple lines.
2. Open the strings.xml file of your project and create a new string (ex. `<string name="my_multiline_textview></string>`).
3. Copy and paste each paragraph from your text inside the tags, putting an `\n` at the end.
4. As many `\n` you put at the end of paragraph, as many lines between them.
5. Insert a new textView on your layout and associate it with the multiline string created on steps 2, 3 and 4 (`android:text="@string/my_multiline_textview"`).
6. Go back to the Graphical Layout and see the magic happening :-)

I hope this info can help yo all. See ya.

Answer (score 3):

Change how many lines and limit the amount of characters

android:inputType="textMultLine"
android:maxLength="180"
android:lines="5"
android:maxLines="5"

Comment: While this code may work, you should add some text describing why.

Comment: its working. what I am looking for. thanks. I set maxWidth="100dp".

Answer (score 2):

You need this 4 properties:

1. `android:layout_width` (set a value let's say 300dp)
2. `android:ellipsize="end"`
3. `android:maxLines="number of lines u want"`
4. `android:singleLine="false"`

for example:
[image]