# How to display dynamic bitmaps in TextView?

Tags: android

I have seen some examples of external bitmap files being shown in TextView control. In my case, I get the bitmap as binary data from a database. I need to show the bitmap along with some text in TextView control. I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. An example would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are displayed in a `TextView` by incorporating [an `ImageSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) into the `Spannable` that is the "text" shown by a `TextView`.

See [SpannableString with Image example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176033/spannablestring-with-image-example) for the basic mechanics. In that example, they use a `Drawable` resource, but there is an `ImageSpan` constructor that takes a `Bitmap`, which you could create via a `BitmapFactory` and obtain from wherever you need to.