# how to set multiple spanned with text on text view in android

Tags: java, android, chat, emoji, spannablestring

I am working on chat. I want to set all emoji icon on text view with text. I have tried by many way but either I am able to set text or a single emojiicon on text. How to set multiple emoji icon with text on text? I have search lots of on google  but I did not find anything with working mode.

```
String text = "hello";                                
for (int i = 0; i < emojilist.length-1; i++) {
    Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src ='"+ emojilist[i] +"'/>",
        imageGetter, null); 
    textviewobject.setText(cs);
}
```

Comment: dont use that crappy Html.fromHtml, use SpannableStringBuilder instead

Comment: can you write any code for it ?

Comment: i don't think so,  however you can ask uncle Google for SpannableStringBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
String html="";
for (int i = 0; i < emojilist.length-1; i++) { 
     html += "<img src ='"+ emojilist[i] +"'/>";
}

Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml(html, imageGetter, null); 
textviewobject.setText(cs);
```

And if you want to use `SpannableString` try:
[SpannableString with Image example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176033/spannablestring-with-image-example)