# Make TextView to expand to fill container space (with multiple views) then truncate

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a layout where I have a two TextViews horizontally next to each other. What I am trying to achieve is a view where the second TextView is aligned to the right of the first, but if the TextView in the first gets too long it will truncate when the right edge of the right TextView hits the edge of the container. The text is set dynamically and can be of varying lengths.

A diagram of what I am trying to achieve is below (yellow = container, red box = second TextView):[image: diagram]

The code I have at the moment is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
        android:background="@drawable/textView2Background"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the first TextView is only truncating when it hits the end of the container, at which point the second TextView has been pushed outside it and is no longer visible.

Thanks

Comment: do you definitely need to use a textview for this? Have you explored the possibility of a spannable string?

Comment: Unfortunately the second TextView has a specific background which needs to be applied. I could turn it into an ImageView instead, but I would still be faced with the same issue

Comment: You can give fixed width to first tetxview with singleline=true

Comment: @Michael by background do you mean a color?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's a specific image which has to be shown. Also @Jatin the text is dynamically set (updated question to include this) so I can't give it a fixed width

Comment: you can divide that yellow background in 2 parts using weight. so your red textview reside in 2nd part.

Comment: But then the first TextView would not correctly adjust to fit the text?

Comment: Okay, you could look into an image span

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast would this be able to deal with my use case above? Where the image wouldn't go off the screen and the text before would be truncated?

Comment: depending on the size of the image / device as well, it could go to the next line if it is too big. But it would still be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/textView2Background"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ImageSpan, check out this previous question:

[SpannableString with Image example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176033/spannablestring-with-image-example)

Comment: Unfortunately it has to all be on one line :( thanks for your help