# how can I set drawable background just to a number string into another string in android?

Tags: android, textview, spannable, background-drawable

is there any way to set background (xml circular drawable) to a number or any string between another string ?

**I have (for example) this text in the textView** (*copied from stackoverflow*):

> You are setting the text on bookDisp(I guess that this is the TextView) and then instead of using the text from that 54 TextView you do a compare between the TextView object(bookDisp) and the test String that will fail. You'll probably want to do:

**my xml circular drawable**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<size android:width="48dp" android:height="48dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="24dp" />
    <solid android:color="#00838F"/>
</shape>
```

i want to set `circular drawable` as a background just for the `54` number in that TextView.

can I use `Spannable` class for that ? if yes, how?

**Thanks**

Comment: You can take help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176033/spannablestring-with-image-example

Comment: Thank you Jibran Khan, it worked but now I just see the background , no any number

Comment: can you verify that the background and textview text color are not same

Comment: no it's not i'm sure

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library to draw any drawable as background of characters in TextView.you can even customize the selection style for EditText.the address is [md2tv](https://github.com/7heaven/md2tv)

here is how it looks like:
[image]

with customize selection style:


[image]