# Android text formatting

Tags: android, text, formatting

I need to format text like on the picture - some part of text must be in round rectangles like with shape background. Tried to use HTML formatting, but it does not work. Didn't find information how to implement it with span.

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: you can use drawables for this

Comment: HTML and CSS do help if you do it correctly.

Comment: Html  and css not helped ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your custom shape drawable and use `Spannable` to set it in your `TextView`.

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(your string); 
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_drawable); 
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
textView.setText(ss);
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177667/3134215) answer for more

Comment: I tried. But custom shape replaces or covers text, that must be in this shape. Shape is rectangle with solid transparent color and stroke of few px.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a drawable and set it as background for the textview

here is an example :

create a shape.xml in your drawable folder

here is a sample of code you can put in shape.xml file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="17dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />

    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="60dp" />

</shape>
```

You can make changes for color and corners as you need in this shape.xml

then set that as a background for your text view
Your layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/First_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like :

[image]

Comment: No, this not fits me.... some bordered text can be part or inside sentence!! By your way all text will be in shape! )

Comment: If you know what text you want borderlined you can put that in another textview and then use drawable for that textview only

Comment: In any case HTML and CSS will help you better :)

Comment: Can you help me with html example?