# How to align textview below and right of imageview?

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am working on a UI in which i want to align my Textview to right of ImageView as well as below of that same ImageView. I want this because, if i align the TextView Right of the ImageView, its leaving some empty space below the ImageView.

Below are the screenshots:

**Current Situtaion:**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6J8T8u_aeWrWWptZTJqTzVMTkk

**Requirement:**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6J8T8u_aeWrbXVnNVJEd0g2dWM

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.meg7.widget.RectangleImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivUserProfilePictureWOQ"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_image" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_woq_quote_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivUserProfilePictureWOQ">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_woq_user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_woq_user_quotes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Qoute"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_woq_tags"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivUserProfilePictureWOQ"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_woq_tags"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="tags" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_woq_likes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="likes" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possiblle duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image

Comment: @AppsFreax your Text is both side okay Image  View Right Side and bottom side?

Comment: Use [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html). 
Have a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3177667/5373110)

Answer (score 0):

So i just created a `xml` as u require  , Just use this in your project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="7dp">

                <com.meg7.widget.RectangleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivUserProfilePictureWOQ"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/splash_image" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_woq_quote_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_woq_user_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:text="Einstien" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_woq_user_quotes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="This is dummy text and check use this in project , do tell me if its working fine or not ......."
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_desciption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="ExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExample"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_woq_tags"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_woq_tags"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="tags"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_woq_likes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="likes"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: **wrong!** He required ONE TextView, not `tv_woq_user_quotes` and `tv_desciption`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinventing the wheel, use library if you can: http://deano2390.github.io/FlowTextView/