# How to set Drawable from xml vector inside ImageSpan

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

How to set `Drawable` from xml vector inside an `ImageSpan`?
I use this two methods below. But my icon didn't show. When I use png from drawable resource icon shows up. Any idea?

```
private void setupEmptyListInfoBox() {
        Drawable icon = loadVectorFromResources(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_add_circle_24dp);
        ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(icon, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        String info = getString(R.string.empty_weight_list_info);
        int iconPosition = info.indexOf("|");

        SpannableString text = new SpannableString(info);
        text.setSpan(is, iconPosition, iconPosition + 1, 0);

        mEmptyListInfo.setText(text);
    }

public static Drawable loadVectorFromResources(Context context, int resId) {
    Drawable drawable;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), resId, context.getTheme());
    } else {
        drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resId, context.getTheme());
    }
    return drawable;
}
```

Comment: Just to know, have you tried putting it in XML just to check if it works non programmatically?

Comment: @user6547359 vector is correct, it works in xml e.g. android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_add_circle_24dp" in TextView. I create it from vector assets(android studio).

Comment: Try taking a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176033/spannablestring-with-image-example maybe it's just a bounds issue.

Comment: @user6547359 setBounds works perfect, icon shows up, thx!

Comment: @user6547359, Thanks. You save my day.

Answer (score 4):

I have just managed to load a vector into an `ImageSpan` by doing:

```
Drawable myDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_drawable);
myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

ImageSpan myImageSpan = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
SpannableString mySpannableString = new SpannableString(context.getString(R.string.my_string));
mySpannableString.setSpan(myImageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Icon has parent layout maximum width and height with this code, setBounds doesnt do anything even if i do something like setBound(0,0,,20,20), do you have any solution for that? how we can scale vector xml drawables?