# Android using icon in text of TextView

Tags: android, textview, icons, user-experience

I´d like to use icons in the text of a TextView. (Not in front or in the end of it.) The basic idea is a short infobox, telling the user, that these fancy three lines up there are the menu. (Since it is not possible to write "Menu" below them, except I want to handle all the click events myself too. *sigh*)
So my text should be something like this:
[image: icon in text]

Right now this is just an icon added at the end of the textview, but as you can clearly see, it looks very ugly, and only works with a fixed screen-size. In landscape mode the icon would be at the completely other side of the screen, than the text.
Therefore I am searching for some way to write icons inside of the text.
I was thinking about something like "Um das Menü zu öffnen, tippe auf @drawable/sandwich" in the string resources or similar. (Which obviously doesn´t work like that, sadly.)

Is this possible? Or, if not, is there maybe some secret trick to add a text to the sandwich icon in the action bar at the top, without creating my custom layout?
Around 50% of my users have issues realizing it is a menu, since they are not used to a lot of apps.

Comment: https://github.com/AAkira/CompoundIconTextView

Comment: please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177667/6076979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using SpannableString. See the below example:

```
val modifiedText = "your-text-here %icon%" // you can use resource string here
val span = SpannableString(modifiedText)
val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.your_image, null)
drawable?.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight)
val image = ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.BOTTOM)
val startIndex = modifiedText.indexOf("%icon%")

//Replace %icon% with drawable
span.setSpan(image, startIndex, startIndex + 6, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
yourTextView.setText(span)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`VerticalImageSpan`](https://gist.github.com/XiaNaLee/b7db76e9a89d516315a6) which is an extension to [`ImageSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan).

And use the following `TextView` extension function takes in the index in the `TextView` that you want to place the drawable in; a drawable, the desired image width & height.

```
fun TextView.addDrawableAt(index: Int, @DrawableRes imgSrc: Int, imgWidth: Int, imgHeight: Int) {
    val ssb = SpannableStringBuilder(this.text)

    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, imgSrc) ?: return
    drawable.mutate()
    drawable.setBounds(
        0, 0,
        imgWidth,
        imgHeight
    )
    ssb.setSpan(
        VerticalImageSpan(drawable),
        index - 1,
        index,
        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    this.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}
```