# TextView with drawableEnd in ConstraintLayout line wrap issue

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` which contains a `TextView` that has an small image at the end of the text. This issue I'm having is that long text is not wrapping. If I fix the constraints on the `TextView` so that long text wraps the image at the end goes to the end of the screen:

Screenshot:

[image]

If I add `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` to the `TextView` the long text wraps but the image at the end doesn't:

[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@drawable/all_circle_white_bg"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_row_item_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_row_item_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:breakStrategy="simple"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_action_open_episode_list"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_row_item_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:breakStrategy="simple"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#A1A0A0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscription_row_item_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/subscription_row_item_title"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want your icon, to not go beyond the parent screen, if the text is long enough, and truncate the overflowing text with ellipses??

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: In the second line, I'd like the small icon to wrap with the text

Comment: what do you mean by *wrap with the text*?

Comment: I want the small icon to always be at the end of the text, even when it wraps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of drawables associated with a *TextView* apply to the start, top, end and bottom of the *TextView* itself and not the text contained within. This is the behavior that you see.

You can use an [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan) to associate a drawable with the end of the text but this will have to be done programmatically.

```
    val image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_open_in_new_24)!!
    val imageSize = textView.lineHeight / 2
    image.updateBounds(bottom = imageSize, right = imageSize)
    val imageSpan = ImageSpan(
        image,
        DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE
    )
    val spannable = SpannableString("${textView.text} ")
    spannable.setSpan(
        imageSpan, spannable.length - 1, spannable.length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
    )
    textView.text = spannable
```

[image]

Here the icon is positioned at the end of the text and replaces the final space character.

Answer (score 6):

To fix this you need to:

1. `wrap_content` the width to keep the `drawableEnd` stick to the end of the text, and to avoid sticking it to the end due to the `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`
2. Set the `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"` in order to bias the `TextView` to the start

When the `TextView` content expands, the `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` will be effective

Applying those to the `TextView`:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/subscription_row_item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:breakStrategy="simple"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_action_open_episode_list"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

[image]

Comment: But I want the icon to wrap with the text. so it is always to the direct right of the last word. So in your top screenshot the mail icon would be to the right of the word "text" on the second line. I'm thinking it is either not possible or I'm thinking of this wrong.

Comment: This is not the behavior of drawableEnd. As its name implies it is a drawable at the end of the textView box.. Not the text itself.. You need to add a drawable within the text as a content. And this has nothing to do with the ConstraintLayout

Comment: @KrisB [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068263/android-using-icon-in-text-of-textview/68070920#68070920) could help you

Comment: I see. I guess I was confused. That link you sent helped. I need to add the icon to the text itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@drawable/all_circle_white_bg"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_row_item_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_item_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/subscription_row_item_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subscription_row_item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:breakStrategy="simple"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_action_open_episode_list"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_row_item_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:breakStrategy="simple"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#A1A0A0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_item_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/layout_item_title"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about that put I was hoping there was a more elegant solution. I mean it's not that long of text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).