# Can you add an icon inside (not to the side) a longer TextView?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview

Is it possible to add an icon to a TextView as such:
[image]

All the things I have tried position the icon outside the TextView field.
(such as adding a ImageView or adding drawableEnd to the TextView)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do it using `SpannableString`, check my answer to ta similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068263/android-using-icon-in-text-of-textview/68069153#68069153

Comment: Thanks! That works, is it possible to add a clickListener to the icon?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can insert image in textview

```
android:drawableEnd="@drawable/img_example
```

for right side of textview and

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/img_example"
```

for left side of textview. before you have to insert an image or icon in the folder `drawable`