# Android Layout Wrap Around Image?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I currently have 2 textviews one is a number and the next is some text. The number appears in the top lefthand corner of the screen and the text is meant to appear next to it. But what I really want is the text to wrap around the number next to and under it. Is there a way of doing this?

Like you can wrap text around an image in something like word.

Comment: Can you show an example (mock-up) of what you'r trying to achieve? I understand your example of wrapping text around images but I don't understand wrapping text around text?

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463221/427225. You can change the Image class to the TextView class and it will work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be accomplished without writing your own class extending `ViewGroup`. It's either that, or embedding a `WebView`for displaying this part of the screen.

Comment: Can a webview only be pointed at external pages. I mean could you write a html page store it on the device and call it for this view?

Comment: You can do that, or you can make it load a HTML formatted string; this solution might work better for you, since you have to build the string at runtime.

Comment: ah that sounds ok, have you got anywhere i can see an example? Thanks for your help

Comment: The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) has some examples. See especially the `loadData` method.