# customizing the myleadingmargin2 class to allow l right sided images

Tags: java, android, layout, customization, word-wrap

I've figured out how to wrap text around an image using the myleadingmargin2 class but it only works with the image on the left side of the text body. I know that the dir variable in drawleadingmargin can change that i just don't know when or where to set it.

Comment: Sorry I meant MyLeadingMarginSpan2 class from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image/8463221#8463221