# Textview wrapping around image android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I was wondering how can I wrap a text around an image?
I have found several solutions but all of them seems to me outdated or am I wrong?
The best solutions that I could find are these ones:
[How to layout text to flow around an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image) 
[text wrapping around image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313898/text-wrapping-around-image-in-android)

Is there not something built in already, since we are in api version 19 and I guess this could be useful!

Comment: have you tried putting the imageview within the textview?

Comment: @Pierre: A compound drawable will remain at its place reserving a "column" and the text won't flow under it (it will only be in its own "column"). So, you'd see a column for the image and a column for the text, not the text wrapping around the image.

Comment: I think the first link you provided answers your question beautifully (thanks for sharing).

Comment: Hi! @Tobor, thx for the good explanation! But has no one a solution because I can imagine that this should be done, which the first link already points out?!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and was about to just use a webview with html/css (which is still probably the best way). But there is a library here which appears to do it: https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView