# How to wrap text around image on android?

Tags: android

Can you please tell me if there is a good way to layout text around image? Like this:

> text text text text  text text text text
> text text text ---------- text text text
> text text text |---------| text text text
> text text text |---------| text text text
> text text text |---------| text text text
> text text text ---------- text text text
> text text text text text text text text

I have tried to get a good way by follow
[text wrapping around image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313898/text-wrapping-around-image-in-android)
https://github.com/goingkilo/flowing-text-for-android-
https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

But, this tutorials couldn't give a correct result for me.

thanks very much.