# Android - How to add Image to TextView with possibility to stay text around the Image

Tags: android

I have question how to add Image to TextView in Android on some specific location with possibility to locate text around this image..

Something like that...

[image]

Comment: You should just be able to set your Imageview whereever you want, then set your TextView to "Wrap_Content".  It should automatically flow around the image.

Comment: Yes, but i want to add dynamically pictures to this textview and count of this images will be different to every text view...

Comment: Right.  And you can dynamically change your text too.  This is built in to the UI.

Comment: This is no easy way to do this except for creating your own custom view...you can also try adding spannable to textview and see if it meets your requirement

Comment: @durdnpoisn That is not correct, `wrap_content` doesn't magically make text flow around the image. `wrap_content` is used so that the layout dimensions are set to the dimensions of the text inside the `TextView`. What he needs is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463221/394933

Comment: yes, but what must I do, if I want to add picture on right side, or in the center of screen and text around it?