# Have image inline with a paragraph of text in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, lazy-loading

I want to have a photo in line with a paragraph of a text in my Android app. Like the photo below:

[image]

For that, I have used a SpannableString with an ImageSpan:

```
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(mContext, R.drawable.image);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("This is a sample text");
text.setSpan(is, 0, 10, 0);
myTextView.setText(text);
```

However, the image is placed only on the first line of the paragraph.

How can I achieve this layout? 
And please note that later I would like to download the image in the background (lazy loading in a ListView).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FlowTextView`](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView) looks like it should have what you want, though I have not tried it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it looked like to be what I wanted. 
I just tried it but I have a couple of problems with this library: 
1. Performance: When used in a ListView, scrolling becomes less smooth even when there is no Image inside it. I'm pretty sure 'FlowText' is causing the problem because if I replace it with TextView, everything is smooth. 
2. Functionalities of ListView such as 'OnItemClickListener' don't work. 
So, is there any alternative library to 'FlowTextView'?

Comment: @SabaJamalian: http://grishma102.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-make-text-flow-around-images-in.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image