# How to draw floating text around rectangles in Android

Tags: android, textview, text-rendering

I need to draw some text in a rectangle, but some rectangular areas inside the rectangle must remain blank, since there will be images or other content inserted in those areas:

[image]

What's the recommended approach for this?

- Is there some View subclass that can render such text?
- Do I have to render it myself, using `StaticLayout` and the like?
- Or is there another way?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image

Comment: Thank you, this looks great for the left-top area, but how about other areas where the text should be floated around, like the one in the right bottom?