# How to have Text left and below image

Tags: android

I want to display Text left and below image.

```
+---------------------------+
| Text................ Image|
+.......(remain text)........+
```

Comment: Please show code of what you have tried to far

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this code

```
String text = getResources().getString(R.string.text);
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
ss.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(6, 230), 0, ss.length(), 0);

TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
textview.setText(ss);

class MyLeadingMarginSpan2 implements LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2 {
    private int margin;
    private int lines;

    MyLeadingMarginSpan2(int lines, int margin) {
        this.margin = margin;
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
        if (first) {
            return margin;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir,
                                  int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text,
                                  int start, int end, boolean first, Layout layout) {}
    @Override
    public int getLeadingMarginLineCount() {
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the Layout xml file, Just add to the ImageView this attribute:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text"
```

this will make it to the right of the Text, and then to make distance between them use this attribute:

```
android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
```

And for the Other text use instead of toRightOf - `android:layout_below="@id/text"`   and then keep distance from the starting of the screen using marginRight again.. assign this with the correctly ID's of the texts and Images.

EDIT WITH POSSIBLE CODE:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />





    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Note that layout_toRightOf only works in a RelativeLayout

Comment: @DavidBalas thank you there are one text only, i want it completed under the image

Comment: @FrankD. Thanks, Actually I didn't knew that. also, Ahmed, I am editing my answer now with a possible complete code and result.

Comment: thank you  @DavidBalas  i used LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2

Comment: Please count this as solved using the tick near my answer and press the Up arrow :P