# Android XML: Using ellipsize when a TextView contains another TextView?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

[image]

As shown in the Design, I need a TextView which ellipsizes when it encounters another TextView (let's forget the small arrow image for now). The Expand button is at bottom, while the max-height of the container is fixed.

I am posting the code that doesn't work for now as TextViews overlap. Please suggest changes.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/expandable"
    tools:context="akshay.expandableview.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="208dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="204dp"
    android:background="#abcdef"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:text="It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)."/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expand_btn"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#fedcba"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Expand"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your `TextView` is ellipsized:

```
boolean isElipsized = false;
Layout layout = textview1.getLayout();
if(layout != null) {
    int lines = layout.getLineCount();
    if(lines > 0) {
        int ellipsisCount = layout.getEllipsisCount(lines-1);
        if (ellipsisCount > 0) {
            isElipsized = true;
        } 
    } 
}

if(isElipsized) {
    //show the "show more" view
}
```

To flow one TextView around another, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image) question