# How to write the whole code regarding wrapping text around image

Tags: java, android

[image]

Im trying to implement 'wrap text around image' but I'd rather write it step by step on my own so I can understand it fully.

Can somebody tell me how to do so? Any websites worth recommending regarding this issue?

Comment: The request is a bit ambiguous. Can you upload a sketch of what you need to achieve. Also, are you not able to achieve this by creating custom ViewGroup?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image

Comment: @KMP I've updated my post with  example of what I want to achieve. Please have a look. I also wanna use this code for multiple Fragments.

Comment: @Cheticamp thank you. I've seen this code but still is not that well explained to do it on my own.

Comment: You will need to provide a little bit more information, like what you’ve tried and what didn’t work for ppl to be able to help you.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini thank you for your comment. The thing is that I don't know how to write it therefore i'm seeking explanation/guidance step by step or maybe people who know how to write such code.

Comment: If you really want to get a starting point, Google is perhaps easier… I searched literally: "android wrap text around image” and the first result already gives you a starting point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image now you say it’s not “well explained to do it on your own” ok, *what part of it you don’t understand*? Perhaps you need to ask 20 more basic questions, before you can understand what is involved in making this to work on an Android system. Break the problem in small chunks. You’re trying to fly before learning to walk.

Comment: Nobody is going to write this for you for free on StackOverflow, so you need to come up with a concise idea of what you’ve done and how it doesn’t work. Then people will guide you. But if you don’t make it into small problems, nobody will have the time/will to spend 5 hours writing code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think [FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/flowtextview) is exactly what you need.