# Textview starting next to view on a line and back to begining on the next

Tags: android, textview, spanned

I'm sorry I didn't find a clearer title :/ I'm not english native, if you've a better idea, please tell me.

I'm looking for coding a view like that :

[image: wanted result]

my problem is to start the body of my cell next to the name of the name of the author (which length is obviously unknown and variable). The name (blue text) and pic are clicable, the pic is a custom view.

Have you encountered a problem like this ?

I could play with Spanned, but the custom round imageview is making it difficult. its width is fixed in dp btw, maybe I can add a padding to the first line ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to layout text to flow around an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image)