# Constrain TextView in two views at the same time

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have to build a layout like this:

[image: I'm trying to build a layout like this]

There are two `TextView`, the blue and the black one.

String inside "black" `TextView` should be placed after "blue" `TextView` and if the text is too long jump down like if it was constrained also to the right of the image.
I can't use `SpannableString` and stuff because the "blue" `TextView` may be an `ImageView` in some cases.

I'm trying to use `ConstraintLayout` which I think is the most completed layout we have, but I can not figure it out.

I will appreciate if someone can show some component, approach or workaround to solve this.
Thanks!

----- EDITED ----
Another example:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in detail why SpannableString was useless?

Comment: Can not be only one TextView, because the "blue" one can be an ImageView in some cases so the "black" TextView behaviour should be the same independent of the first View is anchored . Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use a span to place the black text within the *TextView* of the blue text. If the black text is within an *ImageView* then constrain the black text *ImageView* to the leftmost *ImageView*. When you have black text which is not in an *ImageView*, make the *ImageView's* visibility equal to "gone".

But let's assume that you have two *TextViews* with text that cannot be combined.

**Case 1 - Two *TextViews***

In addition to the leftmost *ImageView*, there are two *TextViews*. One holds blue text and one holds black text. The goal is to make these two *TextViews* appear like they are part of a single *TextView* such that the black text immediately follows the blue text.

To do this, position the black *TextView* to completely overlay the blue *TextView*. This can be easily accomplished with a *ConstraintLayout*.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dandelion_flower" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBlue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Blue text that spane more than one line of its TextView."
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBlack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="This is some black text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Without adjustment, the black text will just appear on top of the blue text. The goal now is to pad out the blue text *TextView* will enough space so that it moves to the end of the blue text. We can do this by adjusting the black text with newline characters (to move it down) and space characters (to move it over). One place to do this is in the `onCreate()` function. (See comments in the following code.)

```
// Wait for the layout to complete before getting measurements.
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textBlue).doOnNextLayout {
    val blueText = it as TextView
    val blackText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textBlack)
    // The TextViews have been laid out. Determine how many lines are used for the blue text.
    val blueLayout = blueText.layout
    val blueLineCount = blueText.layout.lineCount
    // And the width in pixels of the last line.
    val lastLineWidth = blueLayout.getLineWidth(blueLineCount - 1)
    // We will skip over the full lines with newline characters and pad out the last line
    // with spaces.
    val newLines = "\n".repeat(blueLineCount - 1)
    val spaceWidth = blackText.paint.measureText(" ")
    val padChars = " ".repeat((lastLineWidth / spaceWidth).toInt() + 1)
    blackText.text = "$newLines$padChars${blackText.text}"
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

You may need to make some adjustments to the views to make this work, but this is the general idea.

**Case 2 - One *TextView* and an *ImageView* with Text**

In this case, the *ImageView* with text is constrained to the other *ImageView* and positioned below the *TextView*. How this is accomplished depends on your requirements.

One layout can be used for both cases. In case #1, the second *ImageView* would have its visibility set to "gone" or "invisible". In case #2, the black text *TextView* would have its visibility set to "gone" or "invisible".

I originally thought that a [*LeadingMarginSpan*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LeadingMarginSpan) would be the way to go, but it runs into difficulties if the black text should start on any line but the first.

---

If you want to flow text around an *ImageView* [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image) Stack Overflow question and answer(s) should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Case #1 is really original and works as expected! The problem comes in Case #2, when you already noticed it's not easy (or even imposible) anchor `TextView` to the left one view and if the text is too long jump below that view... Did you see my second screeshot of my Question? You can see better what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Ricard I have the black text as potentially an ImageView and not the blue as you do state.. I will correct that. I am unclear on what the second example is representing. Which part is a TextView and which the ImageView? If you are wanting the text of an ImageView to flow like text in a TextView then, I believe, that you are out of luck.

Comment: sorry if I explained bad.  In the second image I posted, the "comma" is an ImageView and the text a TextView, the text inside TextView starts at the end of the ImageView and goes below when it can without covering ImageView (the comma).

Comment: @Ricard Let's see if I understand: The photo is one ImageView and the comma is another separate ImageView. The name is one TextView and the rest of the text is another TextView. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: @Ricard See the last line of the answer. I think that is what can help. You will also need to make adjustments to the views depending upon whether the second ImageView is in use or not probably through the visibility property.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try [Google's FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) with flexWrap attribute set to wrap

Comment: Thanks for the option, but works half. I have been playing with `FlexBoxLayout` but I only   achieve make "black" `TextView` jump below entirely, but not like the image I posted. I need the second line jump below not the entire `TextView`

Comment: I added another example of what I need to achieve In my question!