# How to Spread the TextView According to the space

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I Want to make this type of Layout.

[Here the text view acquired place according to space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keI9d.png)

And I am getting this.[here the text is not spread according to the empty space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmaDJ.png)

Is there any way to achieve that type of layout?
please help me, anyone, I am new to android.

Comment: Use constraint layout as root and set attribute "bottom to the bootom of "to textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library to wrap text around child layouts.
https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

Here is a similar question that has been asked before, you may refer to it as well.

[How to layout text to flow around an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51933272/14492452)

Comment: is it possible to set text in  flowTextView like "flowTextView.setText(R.string.dummy_text)" this shows me error when I try to set like this.

Comment: No, it is not possible. See this link [How to use](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use)